# CSS3 transition behave different on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, css-transitions

I'm working on a pure-css off-canvas menu, following [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css-off-screen-navigation-menu/).

The code is simple, the site-wrap div is supposed to translate to the right when the nav-trigger checkbox is checked. So the navigation div can appear underneath.

```
.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.site-wrap {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
  left: 100px;
}

.nav-trigger + label, .site-wrap {
 -webkit-transition: left 0.2s ease;
  transition: left 0.2s ease;
}
```

It works perfectly on desktop browsers (tested in Firefox and Chromium). But on mobile the transition behave weirdly : the wrapper is scaled down instead of translated.

Differences between desktop browsers and mobile, it looks like a viewport issue. I'm using this basic meta tag :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

I don't know what's wrong. This [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) tells me that CSS3 transitions are still on "working draft". But I think that what I want is really simple, and that it should be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dealt with it by changing the CSS3 method. I used

```
transform translate3d(100px,0,0)
```

instead of making a transition between two positions. It works on mobile, but the transition is more brutal.